# How to correctly insert time and date into a table?

Tags: coldfusion

I't tyring to insert a time AND date into a table using a form.

```
<tr>
    <td> Date (Please enter date format mm/dd/yyyy.):</td>
        <td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="date_used" SIZE="10"  VALIDATE="date"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td> Time (Please enter time format hh:mm tt):</td>
            <td><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="time_used" SIZE="10"  VALIDATE="time" ></td>
                </tr>

.....
<CFSET date_used = #DateFormat(CREATEODBCDATETIME(date_used), "mm/d/yyyy")#>
<CFSET time_used = #DATEFormat(CREATEODBCTIME(time_used),"h:mm tt")#>
```

But when I insert it into the table I get a error

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Which is on the line im inserting the time_used into the table.
Is there a better way to insert a specific time and date into a table?

Comment: You need to lower case the second DATEFORMAT to #DateFormat. That's the first error i see.
also try something like this.
<cfset newdate = #DateFormat(Trim(date_used), "mm-dd-yyyy")# />

Comment: the error is coming from the time_used , but i made the changes

Comment: You're trying to use dateformat for a time... use #TimeFormat

Comment: @KRUKUSA why would the case matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all Dateformat and TimeFormat return strings and you want a datetime object.  The way to get that is with ParseDateTime.

```
 <cfset YourDateTime = 
    ParseDateTime(form.Date_used & ' ' & form.time_used, 'mask goes here')>
```

Then in your query, use the cfsqltype attribute of cfqueryparam to separate the date and time.

```
insert into table (datefield, timefield)
values
(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#YourDateTime#">
, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#YourDateTime#">
)
```

You can look up the mask to use for ParseDateTime().

Those are the basics.  You will have to do a lot of input validation of course.  You might also want to verify that it's necessary to make users enter the seconds portion of the time.