# Coldfusion datepicker dd/mm/yyyy but MySQL stay with format yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: html, coldfusion

`Datepicker` is an option for user easy to pick the date to fill the form. In coldfusion, there is a fill form that need to use `datepicker` and after user selected the date and fill the form with format yyyy/mm/dd by default format which is MySql can read. If i change into dd/mm/yyyy and click save into MySql will get error because from what i know default format for MySql is yyyy/mm/dd.

```
<input type="text" name="Date_joined" size="auto" style="border:0px"required="yes">
```

This is the function to popup datepicker :

```
<a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar1')">
```

This is logo for datepicker :

```
<img align="right" src="calendar_menu.gif" alt="Select a date" border="0"></a>
```

Is there any solution for user pick a date and input text will display dateformat dd/mm/yyyy but still can save into MySql without error.

Comment: You'll need to parse the user input and create an easy to identify date format like `yyyy-mm-dd` for MySQL.

Comment: Also It is better to prevent user manual input for that field.

Comment: So, you have any solution for my code? give an example

Comment: Eg. if you are trying to make your input `format` to `dd/mm/yyyy`. [link](https://trycf.com/gist/faf41408657fce9210dfeaa32e9a3801/acf2016?theme=monokai) to convert it when you are saving in MySQL.

Comment: https://trycf.com/gist/f5c5fae00e20d3c027c4cb42dc05171d/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Use ColdFusion's parsedatetime() function to convert the form input, which is a string by the way, to a datetime object and send that to your database.

Comment: This is what Dan's describing, only without any "time" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271110/how-to-correctly-insert-time-and-date-into-a-table/24271677#24271677

Comment: If you are going to allow people to type in their own dates, make sure you add a label showing the expected format.

Comment: @DanBracuk - you should post an answer

Comment: `parseDateTime` is pretty horrible and may lead to unexpected results, especially due to the dd/mm mm/dd region difference. You are better off restricting the input to one specific format.

Comment: explanation was good but i'm quite can't really make it without example. anyone could post an answer here ?

Comment: Did you try googling `ColdFusion parsedatetime`?  That will give you examples.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have try google but need a lot of time to make me understand. Could you give which website is good enough for me to understand

Comment: @Alex - Yeah, it's not perfect, but the CF10+ version is a *little* better than before since now it let's you supply a mask for parsing, instead of hoping CF will guess correctly...

Comment: If you are trying to learn ColdFusion by trial and error, it might be worth your while to take a class, or online tutorial.

Comment: [Learn CF in a Week](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/) is a pretty good online resource to quickly learn about ColdFusion.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make MySQL accept a user input in format DD/MM/YYYY so the data will be recorded

If you want to save a **string** of numbers and dashes that *represents* a date in the format you want it displayed on a screen, then just make your database column a CHAR(10) and be done with it.

But, if you want to do calculations against it, aggregate data by it, DO THINGS with it, then save it as a date type. Don't worry about how your database UI represents that date value to you. Maybe it's different from how you want it shown on an HTML page, it doesn't matter. What matters is that as a date object, you can easily use and display that value however you like.

> From what I know, MySQL will only accept datatype date with format YYYY/MM/DD.

Not how that works.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html
>   The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL ***retrieves and displays*** DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. > The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

See that "retrieves and displays" (emphasis mine)? It's just a date object with "00:00:00" as the time portion.

So however your form field accepts the string representation of the date, you need to convert it to a proper date object. Per Dan's suggestion, you can easily use `parseDateTime()` to accomplish this.

`#writeOutput( parseDateTime( now() ) )#` will output `{ts '2018-03-14 15:29:19'}`.

If your form field contains a valid string that represents a date (e.g. `2018-03-14`):

`#writeOutput( parseDateTime( form.myDateField ) )#` will output `{ts '2018-03-14 00:00:00'}`.

So the value will be saved as a date object, without the time portion. When you read the saved value later, just use `dateFormat()` to display it in any format you like.

Comment: *if you want to ...DO THINGS with it, then save it as a date type*  Yep. It's almost always better to save dates as some sort of datetime datatype. (Don't use char/varchar fields unless you know what you're doing) @AdrianJMoreno - Don't forget to use a mask with ParseDateTime() or the results may be wrong for dd/mm/yyyy strings.  https://trycf.com/gist/e153b5098e385a725c2415fcc96356a1/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: Corrected example: https://trycf.com/gist/cc5df7c8487a0f98bca197bd7761372e/acf?theme=monokai

Answer (score 0):

(Moved from comments for greater visibility)

One important addition to [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281811/8895292). In this specific case, you **MUST** use a date mask with [parseDateTime()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html). The mask controls how parseDateTime() interprets the input. Without the correct mask, the results may be wrong for your specific input, namely `dd/mm/yyyy`.

[TryCF Example](https://trycf.com/gist/cc5df7c8487a0f98bca197bd7761372e/acf?theme=monokai)

*Code:*

```
<cfscript>
    dateString = "05/08/2018";
    writeOutput("<br>Without mask = "& parseDateTime( dateString) );
    writeOutput("<br>With mask = "& parseDateTime( dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy") );
</cfscript>
```

*Result:*

```
Without mask = {ts '2018-05-08 00:00:00'} (May 8, 2018)
With mask = {ts '2018-08-05 00:00:00'} (August 5, 2018)
```