# How to save DD/MM/YYYY date to MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, coldfusion

I am new to the developer world. From what I know, MySQL will only accept datatype date with format `YYYY/MM/DD`. If I use dateformat `DD/MM/YYYY` in my web application and click save, an error occurs and no data is recorded (*500-Internal Server error*). How to make MySQL accept a user input in format `DD/MM/YYYY` so the data will be recorded?

```
<cfquery name="testrecorddate" datasource="myData">
INSERT INTO DATE_DATE 
VALUES 
('#Form.RecordDate#')

<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="RecordDate"> 13/03/2018 </textarea>
<input type="Submit" value="Save"><input type="Reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</cfquery>
```

I am using ColdFusion language and still learning. Is it possible to make MySQL accept ColdFusion dateformat `DD/MM/YYYY` so it will stored the data without an error happening?

Comment: Your google search string is `cfqueryparam`.

Comment: @DanBracuk okay, thank you

Comment: Didn't you already open a question about this same issue? [Coldfusion datepicker dd/mm/yyyy but MySQL stay with format yyyy/mm/dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229991/coldfusion-datepicker-dd-mm-yyyy-but-mysql-stay-with-format-yyyy-mm-dd). Duplicate questions are discouraged on S.O. If you need to add more details, update your question instead.

Comment: i did but the question is no fully answer

Comment: Here is a hint.  Your statement, `From what i know MySQL will only accept datatype date with format YYYY/MM/DD.` indicates that you are misinformed.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of the [other question you had already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229991/1636917). As @Ageax said, don't open a new question just update the original question with more details.

Comment: Moved my answer to the original question.

Answer (score -3):

You'll have to parse it out manually before inserting into the database:

```
<cfset form.RecordDate = '#listLast(form.RecordDate, '/')#-#listGetAt(form.RecordDate, 2, '/')#-#listFirst(form.RecordDate, '/')#'>
```

Input of "dd/mm/yyyy" will result in "yyyy-mm-dd" for MySQL.

Comment: MySQL is perfectly happy accepting yyyy-mm-dd into a date field. The question was not asking for a date object. It asked for a format MySQL will store. If you need a real date object you can then `createodbcdatetime()` the result.

Comment: "It asked for a format MySQL will store." MySQL [doesn't store dates in string format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html). They're stored as numbers. Like CF, MySQL attempts to convert [some date strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html), but wrong formats can cause unpredictable results. Always use date objects with date/time columns.

Comment: `2018-03-13` will not give an issue inserting into a date field. It is the correct string format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: actually i want to input 13-03-2018 to MySQL

Comment: That's simply not possible. You have to convert to a string MySQL will accept as a date, or convert to a true date object.